# REDUX concept queries: 2 ways OR 3 ways to access a redux store. Why use thunk and missing createStore parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-reducer

I am learning about react + redux. I have 3 questions related to it.

**query-1:** The ways to access a store inside a component.
According to the official documentation [here](https://fernandobelotto.github.io/react-redux/next/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch/) there are 2 ways

1. hooks(useSelector etc.)
2. connect.

By importing store in our component we can access the store via store.getState() or  store.dispatch()

So aren't there 3 ways?

**query-2:**.  We use thunk so that we can do async operations in our action creator(eg API call). The action creator can return a function (instead of an action). Here is a simple example.

```
    const fetchUser = (data) => {
        return (dispatch) => {
         axios.post('url', data).then(() => { dispatch(action) }).catch();
        }
       }
```

And we can now dispatch fetchUser from our component(eg: dispatch(fetchUser(payload))  )

Why cannot we simply pass dispatch function to fetchUser instead of using thunk, Here is an example

```
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
      fetchUser(payload, dispatch)`
```

Asking because it worked perfectly fine.

**query-3**: While creating a redux store, we pass 3 parameters, 1. reducer 2. [preLoadedState] 3. [enhancers].
I have mostly seen examples as shown below

```
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

OR

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)))
```

Since applymiddleware is a store enhancer, we can see we have skipped second parameter. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

### Q1

As you rightly pointed out there are 2 ways to get Redux State:

- hooks (`useSelector`)
- `connect`

`store.dispatch` or `useDispatch` is not accessing the Redux State.
Instead it is allowing you to mutate the state of the Store by *dispatching actions*.

Think of it as:

- `useSelector` and `connect` are *subscribers* to the Store (they blindly accept changes from the Store)
- `useDispatch` and `store.Dispatch` are *prescribers* to the Store (actions tell the Store what is changing, and what it's new value will be)

### Q2

You can pass the `dispatch` object around, there's nothing wrong with that (per se),  but it could become unclear as to what that object is.
In both examples you use, it shows the `dispatch` object being used to *call an action*.
[Thunk](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/redux-redux-thunk) is just used to handle that async behaviour so you don't have to (so much)

### Q3

The reason why `applymiddleware` is called, is because you are then able to pass multiple things into your ReduxStore

For example:

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(promise, thunk)
);
```